# Mysql GROUPing with ORDER based on auto increment column

Tags: mysql

I have to group my anime index according to their AniDB ID and show the values in a DESCENDING order according to file auto increment id.

Here's what I did currently:

```
SELECT
f.id, f.category, f.anidb, f.mal_id, COUNT( * ) AS dupes, f.filename,
a.titles, a.synopsis, a.episodes, a.image, a.rating,
c.name as cat_name, c.id as categoryid
  FROM table_files f
      LEFT JOIN table_anidb a ON a.id = f.anidb
      LEFT JOIN table_categories c ON c.id = f.category
      GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY f.id DESC
```

### PROBLEM:

1. I have Naruto 8 episodes. episode 8's ID is 204. And ep.1 has ID 160. The query return like this:

   ```
   id  |   anidb   |   filename    |   dupes   |   cat_name
   --------------------------------------------------------
   201 |   8692    |   SAO         |   1       |   Series
   200 |   9251    |   RYO         |   1       |   Movie
   .....
   .......
   160 |   239     |   Naruto ep.1 |   8       |   Series
   ```

   But I want Naruto *Episode 8* to be showed in the top of the results instead of *episode 1* in the last.
2. How do I group by anidb and mal_id at the same time with an `OR` logic? So that the grouping can be done even if there is not any anidb ID provided.

Comment: What is the criteria for most recent?

Comment: the auto increment `id`

Comment: You have some weird stuff,you say id 160 I see id 150 and others.

Comment: Good catch! That's just an example. question edited and fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad. 1.

Since `id`, `anidb` and `filename` are all in one table i'm afraid you can't get away from doing a subquery join:

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97c756/16)**

```
SELECT f.id, f.anidb, f.filename 
FROM files f
JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM files GROUP BY anidb) AS f2 
  ON f2.id = f.id
ORDER BY f.id DESC
```

(data flattened for the sake of readibility but you can get the general idea)

Ad. 2.

As for the second problem, you really just have to add second grouping column to the above joined subquery:

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/acac2/1)**

```
SELECT f.id, f.anidb, f.mal_id, f.filename 
FROM files f
JOIN 
  (SELECT MAX(id) as id FROM files GROUP BY anidb, mal_id) AS f2 on f2.id = f.id
ORDER BY f.id DESC
```

The `NULL`'s are distinct from each other (e.g. NULL != NULL) so there's no fear that grouping would melt all the nulled `anidb` rows into one.

Comment: This is perfect! Taking the time and gone through the trouble of actually fiddle them, I really appreciate that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you can use `ORDER BY dupes`

```
SELECT
f.id, f.category, f.anidb, f.mal_id, COUNT( * ) AS dupes, f.filename,
a.titles, a.synopsis, a.episodes, a.image, a.rating,
c.name as cat_name, c.id as categoryid
  FROM table_files f
      LEFT JOIN table_anidb a ON a.id = f.anidb
      LEFT JOIN table_categories c ON c.id = f.category
      GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY dupes DESC
```

For the second problem you can use `CASE` to check if `f.anidb` is null

```
SELECT
f.id, f.category, f.anidb, f.mal_id, COUNT( * ) AS dupes, f.filename,
a.titles, a.synopsis, a.episodes, a.image, a.rating,
c.name as cat_name, c.id as categoryid
  FROM table_files f
      LEFT JOIN table_anidb a ON a.id = f.anidb
      LEFT JOIN table_categories c ON c.id = f.category
      GROUP BY
(CASE WHEN f.anidb IS NULL THEN f.mal_id ELSE f.anidb END )
ORDER BY dupes DESC
```

Comment: For the first part of my problem, I wanted it to ORDER BY f.id. I want the most recent anime to be on the top instead of the most common one.